# CoreMidi with MacRuby

Tags: ruby, macos, midi, macruby, coremidi

I am trying to use the CoreMidi.framework with MacRuby and I am getting hung up on the correct way to implement the CoreMidi mechanisms in Ruby. I have created the MIDIClient and the OutputPort:

```
clientName = "Client"
clientRef = Pointer.new(:uint)
MIDIClientCreate( clientName, nil, nil, clientRef )

portName = "Output"
outport = Pointer.new(:uint)
MIDIOutputPortCreate( clientRef[0], portName, outport )

numberOfDestinations = MIDIGetNumberOfDestinations()
destination = MIDIGetDestination( 0 )
```

After this, I am at a loss for exactly what to do.  I need to create a MIDIPacketList to send to MIDISend, but I'm not sure how this would be done in Ruby. The program hangs when I try to create a packet list with:

```
packetList = MIDIPacketList.new
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this your actual code? In the call to `MIDIClientCreate` I get the error `TypeError: expected instance of Pointer of type '^{OpaqueMIDIClient}', got 'I'`

Comment: This is my actual code. I have framework 'CoreMidi' at the top of the file.  This runs with MacRuby 0.12 (ruby 1.9.2) [universal-darwin10.0, x86_64].

Comment: Ok, I updated to MacRuby 0.12 and created a BridgeSupport file for CoreMIDI and your code runs. Do you get 0 for `numberOfDestinations` and `destination`?

Comment: Yeah, and when I plug in a USB-to-MIDI device, I get 1 for numberOfDestinations, so all seems to be working there.

Comment: This is an interesting puzzle but I'm not sure how much time I'll have to work on this over the next week. In C/Objective-C, you create a buffer and then create a MIDIPacketList that points to that buffer [basically like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668390). So the trick is how in MacRuby do you create a buffer and then tell a MIDIPacketList object that it points to that buffer.

Comment: I have constructed a bundle using C/Objective-C to carry out the MIDI functionality, which can be used in a Ruby app with _require_. But, this doesn't solve the issue, as I would still like to know how to implement this using only Ruby (or whether it is even possible).